# Python code that requires ask to do an IC validation

Tags: python

guys.I am currently a student and took a programming test yesterday in python.
The question was something along the line of asking us to input an IC that starts with T and we are to check for its validation through finding the remainder of this equation 
`x=(int(IC[1])*2+int(IC[2])*7+int(IC[3])*6+int(IC[4])*5+int(IC[5])*4+int(IC[6])*3+int(IC[7])*2+4)%11`

in addition ,they also state that
Z=0,J=1,I=2,H=3,G=4,F=5,E=6,D=7,C=8,B=9,A=10
So basically x needs to have the same value as the value the last letter was assigned to ,for eg. T12345678B is not a real IC as x does not fit the value B is assigned to .However ,I do not know why mt code doesn't work ,can you guys help me please?Thank you

```
IC=str(input("Enter the IC(starting with T) to be validated (all letters to be in caps):"))
x=(int(IC[1])*2+int(IC[2])*7+int(IC[3])*6+int(IC[4])*5+int(IC[5])*4+int(IC[6])*3+int(IC[7])*2+4)%11
J=0
Z=1
I=2
H=3
G=4
F=5
E=6
D=7
C=8
B=9
A=10
if IC[-1] == "J"
IC[-1]=J
elif IC[-1]== "Z"
IC[-1]= Z
elif IC[-1]== "I"
IC[-1]=I
elif IC[-1] =="H"
IC[-1]=H
elif IC[-1] =="G"
IC[-1]=G
elif IC[-1] =="F"
IC[-1]=F
elif IC[-1] =="E"
IC[-1]=E
elif IC[-1] =="D"
IC[-1]=D
elif IC[-1] =="C"
IC[-1]=C
elif IC[-1] =="B"
IC[-1]=B
elif IC[-1] =="A"
IC[-1]=A

if x == y
print ("Validity of the IC: True")
else
print ("Validity of the IC: False")
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  Please read and follow the posting guidelines in the help documentation.  [Minimal, complete, verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) applies here.  We cannot effectively help you until you post your MCVE code and accurately describe the problem.
We should be able to paste your posted code into a text file and reproduce the problem you described.  The code you posted doesn't execute, and "doesn't work" is not a problem specification.

Comment: In addition to satisfying the first comment, you should also explain the meanings of `IC`, `T`, and `validation`. Those do not seem to me to be standard terms--I certainly do not know them in such a context.

Comment: 'T' is just the first letter of the IC which refers to the identity card no of a person.  . In this case we are using that of a country named Singapore which IC has a format of "T12345678J" .

Answer (score 0):

1. Your indentation in the `if` .. `elif` blocks is wrong. Also you are missing semicolons, ie `if IC[-1] == "J":` <- it's bad syntax without the semicolon.
2. Your checksum expression seems to be ignoring the last digit, `ic[8]` (ie `"8"` in `"T12345678B"`). Are you sure this is correct? I presume the multiplier for the last digit is 1.
3. You calculate `x` and then ignore it; then you try to compare to a value `y` which you have not calculated (which will cause a NameError error).
4. I think the underlying problem is (for example) where you have

   ```
   if IC[-1] == "J"
       IC[-1]=J
   ```

   you actually mean to have

   ```
   if IC[-1] == 'J':
       y = 0          # check-code value
   ```

Here is how I would do it:

```
def is_valid_ic(ic_str):
    # force string to uppercase
    ic_str = ic_str.upper()

    # a valid IC must have 10 characters
    if len(ic_str) != 10:
        return False

    # the first character of a valid IC must be 'T'
    if ic_str[0] != 'T':
        return False

    # characters 1..8 must be digits
    try:
        # convert characters to numbers
        a, b, c, d, e, f, g, h = [int(i) for i in ic_str[1:9]]
    except ValueError:
        # some character is not a digit
        return False

    # last character must match checksum
    checksum = (2 * a + 7 * b + 6 * c + 5 * d + 4 * e + 3 * f + 2 * g + h + 4) % 11
    return ic_str[9] == "ZJIHGFEDCBA"[checksum]

def main():
    s = input("Please enter an IC (starting with T): ")

    if is_valid_ic(s):
        print("IC is valid")
    else:
        print("IC is not valid")

if __name__=="__main__":
    main()
```

Comment: sorry I accidentally inputted the extra '8'

Comment: Hi, your code does not really work as I have tried with a fake ic and it proves to be true.
Meanwhile I wrote a new code that finally works regardless of lettercasing:

Comment: IC=str(input("Enter the IC to be validated :"))
x=(int(IC[1])*2+int(IC[2])*7+int(IC[3])*6+int(IC[4])*5+int(IC[5])*4+int(IC[6])*3+int(IC[7])*2+4)%11

if IC[-1] == "J" or IC[-1]=="j":
 y=0
elif IC[-1]== "Z" or IC[-1]=="z":
 y=1
elif IC[-1]== "I" or IC[-1]=="i":
 y=2
elif IC[-1] =="H" or IC[-1]=="h":
 y=3
elif IC[-1] =="G" or IC[-1]=="g":
 y=4
elif IC[-1] =="F" or IC[-1]=="f":
 y=5
elif IC[-1] =="E" or IC[-1]=="e":
 y=6
elif IC[-1] =="D" or IC[-1]=="d":
 y=7
elif IC[-1] =="C" or IC[-1]=="c":
 y=8
elif IC[-1] =="B" or IC[-1]=="b":

Comment: y=9
elif IC[-1] =="A" or IC[-1]=="a":
 y=10
   
if x == y:
 print ("Validity of the IC: True")
else:
 print ("Validity of the IC: False")